# How to sort a list of tuples based on the keys in a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, list-comprehension

I want to sort a list of tuples based on a number of keys. For example, I have this list of tuples:

```
list_t = [(1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 61), (1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 81), (1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 54), (1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 43)]
```

One time I want to sort it by the first, second, third, and fifth element of the tuples:

```
keys = [0, 1, 2, 4]
list_t_sorted = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 61), (1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 81), (1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 54), (1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10), (1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 43)]
```

And another time I need to sort it just by the third element of the tuples:

```
keys = [2]
list_t_sorted = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 61), (1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 81), (1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10), (1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 43), (1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 54)]
```

So far I tried this code but it does not return the expected results:

```
def sort_list(keys, list_t):
    return sorted(list_t, key=lambda l: (l[x] for x in keys))
```

For example, for keys = [0, 1, 2, 4] it returns [(1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 61), (1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 43), (1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 54), (1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 81)] which is not sorted based on the keys.

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: You say it doesn't return the expected results. What _does_ it return?

Comment: A not sorted list of tuples based on the keys. For example, for keys = [0, 1, 2, 4], it returns [(1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 61), (1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 43), (1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 54), (1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 81)], which is not sorted on keys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go. You can read more about `operator.itemgetter` [here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
import operator
list_t = [(1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 61), (1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 81), (1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 54), (1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 43)]
keys = [0, 1, 2, 4]
sorted(list_t, key=operator.itemgetter(*keys))
```

Outputs:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 61),
 (1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 81),
 (1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 54),
 (1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10),
 (1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 43)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

michael_j_ward's answer is a much cleaner solution to your question, but if you want to know what went wrong with your original idea:

You are attempting to sort generator objects, which I am guessing has a different way of equating. A way to show this is by showing what you are actually attempting to sort with a for loop:

```
>>> def sort_list(keys, list_t):
...     for l in list_t:
...             print (l[x] for x in keys)
...     return sorted(list_t, key = lambda l: (l[x] for x in keys))
...
>>> sort_list(keys, list_t)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x105bc1af0>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x105bc1af0>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x105bc1af0>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x105bc1af0>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x105bc1af0>
[(1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 43), (1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 54), (1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 81), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 61), (1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10)]
```

This is obviously not your intended output, and it has to do with how those generators are being compared. If you want to do it with your original idea (without `itemgetter`), explicitly create `tuples` instead of generators:

```
>>> def sort_list(keys, list_t):
...     return sorted(list_t, key = lambda l: tuple(l[x] for x in keys))
...
>>> sort_list(keys, list_t)
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 61), (1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 81), (1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 54), (1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10), (1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 43)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your great clarification!